# mysql insert to multiple tables

Tags: sql, database

The database consist of four tables, customers, orders, order_item and products. currently customers table consist of 2 customers and products table consist of 4 products. lets say cutomer_id: 1, has product_id:1 and product_id:2 in cart.

How can I insert the information both to table orders and order_item where order gets the full name of the customer and customer_id and order_items gets the key of order_id

customers:

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+
| customer_id | first_name | last_name | city     |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+
|       (PK)1 | Joe        | Katz      | Brooklyn |
|       (PK)2 | Mike       | Smith     | Brooklyn |
+-------------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Orders:

```
| order_id | customer_id | order_status | customer_name |
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|   (PK)   | (FK)        |             |                |
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

order_item:

```
+---------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| item_id | order_id | product_id | quantity | list_price |
+---------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|  (PK)   | (FK)     |  (FK)      |          |            |
+---------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

products:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| product_id | product_name | list_price |
+------------+--------------+------------+
|      (PK)1 | jeans        |         45 |
|      (PK)2 | shoes        |        100 |
|      (PK)3 | socks        |          7 |
|      (PK)4 | coat         |        160 |
+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Which database are you trying to do this in?  MySql or Oracle?  A single insert statement will not do both things.  Typically you start a transaction, insert into the parent table and get back the newly created key.  Then you insert into the child table with the key.  Finally you end the transaction.  The transaction syntax and how you return the key from the parent table can depend on the database you are working with.

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags, please add back the one that corresponds to your RDBMS.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk I am using MySql, so without a backend its not possible to do it just with MySql, by executing all the commands at the same time

Comment: If your parent table has a unique index that you know all of the values to, you can insert into the child tables using a subquery to look up the parent key from within the same Sql statements.  There will be separate inserts, but they will be related and known up-front.  For example if your parent table had a unique "SalesOrderNumber" column, you could "insert into salesorderheader (salesorderno) values ('123456');   insert into salesorderdetail (SalesORderHeaderId, ItemCode,quantiy) values (  (Select salesorderheaderid from salesorderheader where salesorderno = '123456'), 'firstItem', 11);

Comment: For you, it looks like the only unique key in the parent table is order_id which looks to be database generated.  You could look it up like this:  begin transaction;  insert into orders (customer_id,...) values ('mikeW',...);  insert into order_items (order_id, item_id, ...)  values (select max(order_id) from orders where customer_id = 'mikeW' group by customer_id), 'new keyboard', ...); commit;  I am assuming that the order_ids are sequential.  The transaction should keep other inserts from cross contaminating the max(order_id) subqueries.